# Cannot assign Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Caster\CutStub to reference held by property App\Entity\AccountName::$accountType

Tags: symfony

I am developing a project by Symfony 6.2. In this project one entity AccountType with many to one relationship another entity AccountCategory.

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AccountTypeRepository::class)]
class AccountType
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;
   
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $code = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $remarks = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'accountType', targetEntity: AccountName::class)]
    private Collection $accountNames;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'accountTypes')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?AccountCategory $accountCategory = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accountNames = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemarks(): ?string
    {
        return $this->remarks;
    }

    public function setRemarks(?string $remarks): self
    {
        $this->remarks = $remarks;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, AccountName>
     */
    public function getAccountNames(): Collection
    {
        return $this->accountNames;
    }

    public function addAccountName(AccountName $accountName): self
    {
        if (!$this->accountNames->contains($accountName)) {
            $this->accountNames->add($accountName);
            $accountName->setAccountType($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAccountName(AccountName $accountName): self
    {
        if ($this->accountNames->removeElement($accountName)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($accountName->getAccountType() === $this) {
                $accountName->setAccountType(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountCategory(): ?AccountCategory
    {
        return $this->accountCategory;
    }

    public function setAccountCategory(?AccountCategory $accountCategory): self
    {
        $this->accountCategory = $accountCategory;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Another Entity:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AccountCategoryRepository::class)]
class AccountCategory
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'accountCategories')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?AccountReport $accountReport = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $code = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 555, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $remarks = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'accountCategory', targetEntity: AccountType::class)]
    private Collection $accountTypes;
   
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accountTypes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAccountReport(): ?AccountReport
    {
        return $this->accountReport;
    }

    public function setAccountReport(?AccountReport $accountReport): self
    {
        $this->accountReport = $accountReport;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemarks(): ?string
    {
        return $this->remarks;
    }

    public function setRemarks(?string $remarks): self
    {
        $this->remarks = $remarks;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, AccountType>
     */
    public function getAccountTypes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->accountTypes;
    }

    public function addAccountType(AccountType $accountType): self
    {
        if (!$this->accountTypes->contains($accountType)) {
            $this->accountTypes->add($accountType);
            $accountType->setAccountCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAccountType(AccountType $accountType): self
    {
        if ($this->accountTypes->removeElement($accountType)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($accountType->getAccountCategory() === $this) {
                $accountType->setAccountCategory(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

   
}
```

When data retrieve for editing of Account Type form then shown below error.

"Cannot assign Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Caster\CutStub to reference held by property App\Entity\AccountCategory::$accountReport of type ?App\Entity\AccountReport"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue related to php version. I had the same issue and just upgrade my php to 8.2 and the issue disapears.

See also --> https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/49091